# Getting an iPad to print on a corporate windows network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printing, ipad

My users want to use an iPad to print to our network printers. The printers are shared using a Windows 2008 R2 Server. I've looked into getting AirPrint to work but haven't had any success.

I would consider a Mac OS X VM or maybe a mac mini on the network.

Comment: Just one hint: You can run an OS X VM legally only on a Mac with MacOS, so this isn't an option.

Comment: @SvenW ESXi 5 can run OS X VMs, but still only allowed on Apple hardware.

Comment: yeah...I'm thinking the $999 mac mini with lion server would be a nice legal fit. I'm still a bit confused about the implementation and how to get it to work with windows.

Comment: This description seems to cover how to set it up on Linux.  That may be cheaper then buying Apple hardware.  You can easily run linux in a VM.  http://www.finnie.org/2010/11/13/airprint-and-linux/

Comment: @Shane Madden: Does ESXi run on Apple hardware? Especially on the XServe?

Comment: @SvenW XServe rev `3,1`, apparently - see [here](http://blogs.vmware.com/guestosguide/2011/08/apple-mac-os-x-server.html).

Comment: I'm going to try the Ubuntu 11.10 beta which apparently has AirPrint Support http://digitizor.com/2011/06/29/ubuntu-apple-airprint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I was successfully able to use AirPrint on my corporate network (I am the sysadmin). I was unable to print to severs shared using SMB Shares. I was only able to successully print to printers with print servers built into them, using their IP Address on port 9100.

1) Install a VM with [Ubuntu 11.11 beta Oneiric Ocelot](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/beta-1/). Update your packages.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

2) Add the printer using [these instructions](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-June/033611.html)

> 1. On your computer start system-config-printer via System -> 
>      Administration -> Printing (GNOME Classic) or via Turn-off-button at
>      the  upper right -> System Settings -> Hardware -> Printing (Unity
>      Natty) or  via the command line (all systems including Unity Oneiric).
> 2. In system-config-printer choose Server -> Settings and activate 
>      "Published shared printers connected to this system". Click OK and
>      then  right-click on the icon of your print queue and choose
>      Properties in the  pop-up menu. In the Policies section of the dialog
>      make sure that  "Shared" is activated.

**YOU MUST ADD THE PRINTER USING HP/APP SOCKET.**

3) Get the AirPrint Generate script from [github here](https://github.com/tjfontaine/airprint-generate). ([More info](http://www.atxconsulting.com/blog/tjfontaine/2010/11/21/automatically-generate-airprint-avahi-service-files-cups-printers))

`./airprint-generate.py`

This will generate `PRINTER.service`files.

`cp PRINTER.service /etc/avahi/services/`

4) edit `/etc/cups/cups.conf` add a line

`ServerAlias *` 
under the line `Port 631`

5) Restart avahi and cups

**NOTE:
To debug use avahi-browse.**

```
avahi-browse --terminate --resolve _ipp._tcp
```

Sources:

http://digitizor.com/2011/06/29/ubuntu-apple-airprint/

[http://www.atxconsulting.com/blog/tjfontaine/2010/11/21/automatically-generate-airprint-avahi-service-files-cups-printers/](http://www.atxconsulting.com/blog/tjfontaine/2010/11/21/automatically-generate-airprint-avahi-service-files-cups-printers)

http://www.finnie.org/2010/11/13/airprint-and-linux/

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-June/033611.html

Answer (score 2):

There are AirPrint home-made daemons you can use (same as there are home-made AirPlay daemons as well), but I think you'll have trouble getting a sysadmin agreeing to install *and support them* on your print servers.

These solutions all involve [installing iTunes and then using its Bonjour service to share the printer](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-20023976-233.html). I haven't actually had success on getting it to work (at home, not at work), but others have.